# Is there a way to jump to specific line?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-2017

How to skip "First Message" or to start async function from n'th line?

```js
async function oneByOne() {
  await talk("First Message");
  await talk("Second Message?");
  await talk("Last Message?");
}
```

Comment: To skip lines conditionally, wrap them in an `if` block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have an array of messages and loop through them

```
async function oneByOne(startIndex) {
        const messages = ["first message", "second message?", "last message?"];
        while (startIndex < messages.length) {
            await talk(messages[startIndex]);
            startIndex++;
        }
}
```

Now, you can feed `oneByOne` an index to start at. If you say `oneByOne(1)`, it will skip index 0